# Sencha Touch 2 - prevent a-href events (a-href event handling)

Tags: cordova, event-handling, dom-events, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha Touch 2 application I need to handle redirection events on my own. By this I mean I need to be able to handle a href events and do the redirection myself.

I'm using the following code:

```
Ext.Viewport.element.addListener("tap", function(e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    // ... my code ...
}, this, {delegate: "a"});
```

By none of the above mentioned functions work (`stopEvent`, `stopPropagation`, `preventDefault`). The application always opens the link in my app web view.

Is here any possible way to disable a href opening links?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually do this this way :

```
Ext.Viewport.element.dom.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') {
        return;
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
}, false);
```

[Try here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#G7f1O)

Hope this helped

Comment: Nice, this solved my issue too. Am willing to lose stackoverflow reputation points for saying Sencha Touch 2.2.1 as of 8/13/2013 is not documented that well. This was just one of the many slew of issues I'm facing during an upgrade project. Kinda' reminds me of IE. #endrant.